# What are the correct pairings between the soul's faculties and the 3 transcendentals?

Tags: catholicism, philosophy, souls, image-of-god, transcendentals

#### The three transcendentals and *imago dei*

Medieval scholastic theology inherited the notions of [transcendentals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendentals) from Greek metaphysics.  CCC 41, interpreting [Wis 13:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Wisdom%2013%3A5&version=NRSVCE), teaches that our soul has the ability to perceive God through the 3 transcendentals Truth, Goodness and Beauty in created things **by resemblance**, because our soul has *imago dei* stamped on it:

> All creatures bear a certain resemblance to God, most especially man, created in the image and likeness of God. The manifold perfections of creatures - their truth, their goodness, their beauty all reflect the infinite perfection of God. Consequently we can name God by taking his creatures" perfections as our starting point, "for from the greatness and beauty of created things comes a corresponding perception of their Creator".

A [*Reasons to Believe* article](https://reasons.org/explore/blogs/reflections/the-3-transcendentals-truth-goodness-beauty) quoted Stephen R. Turley saying that the 3 transcendentals to provide **divine meaning to 3 capacities**:

> Truth, goodness, and beauty are cosmic values that communicate divine meaning to the **intellectual**, **moral**, and **aesthetic** capacities of the human soul, which brings a balance in the soul, which, in turn, harmonizes the human person with divine meaning and purpose of the cosmos, which was considered the prerequisite to human flourishing.

The same article quoted Christian philosopher Peter Kreeft who connects the 3 transcendentals to **created things**:

> When God created, he imbued the cosmos with truth, goodness, and beauty. Philosopher Peter Kreeft says: “Everything that exists is in some way true, good, and beautiful.”

and continues to associate the 3 transcendentals to **3 verbs** "know", "desire", and "love":

> And humans via the imago Dei (image of God) are able **to *know* the truth, *desire* the good, and *love* the beautiful**. The fall of humankind into sin disordered man’s natural capacities but through the redemption found in the life, death, and resurrection of Jesus Christ humans are brought back into a right relationship with God and with these revealed values.

#### My question

It seems that the last 2 pairings are not technically consistent.  Shouldn't it be:

1. ***Know* Truth** by our **reason** (because by **intellectual**  activity in our mind we grasp & form concepts and we reason discursively)
2. ***Love* Goodness** by our **will** (because inspired by divine Love we *ACTIVELY resolve* to love others, usually with great effort unless aided by virtues, in the sphere of Christian **morality**, i.e. love = "willing the good of the other")
3. ***Desire* Beauty** by our **passion** (because our **aesthetic** sensibilities is *PASSIVELY drawn* to all things beautiful or by *being led* to them by simply perceiving or immersing ourselves in them with little effort)

I am seeking a Catholic answer linking Catholic psychology to Catholic doctrine of God.  I hope that CCC, an encyclical, St. Thomas Aquinas, or a post Vatican II theologian says something about it.

#### P.S.

It seems there are other meanings at play here, such as "love" as attraction ("love" is such a complex multivalent word!) or "good" to mean how we desire created goods (such as wealth, honor, food, sex, etc.) we aim to possess to be happy.  I'm simply using that article as a motivating resource to ask this question.

It's important for the answer to this question to get those multiple meanings of the words in order, refined within the discipline of Catholic psychology, so we can focus on the right terminologies for the 3 faculties of our soul (covered heavily in St. Thomas's *Summa*) and how they connect to the 3 transcendentals in Catholic theology.

Comment: classically something is desirable because it is good

Comment: @eques Yes, but isn't that "good" (classical definition) is desired as a teleological goals of our activities, things such as wealth, honor, food, sex, and then when we are satisfied we achieve the state of "happiness"?  In other words, yes, we desire the goods to be **happy**?  But Goodness in the Christian version of the 3 transcendentals seem to connote something else, as "God is good" or "That saint is a good man" connoting **virtues** that operate mainly on the will to impel us to good actions? Many times it's hard for me to do good, I'm not drawn to it like to beautiful music / nature.

Comment: It's not a difference of substance. It's only that the pre-Christian understanding is fundamentally incomplete because nothing besides God can really fully satisfy the desire. The pagan philosophers would certainly recognize the idea of that man is a good man in relation to virtues which lead towards good actions.

Comment: @eques I see.  But since I frame it in the medieval era and later, does my question need clarification?  I would like to know whether Catholic theologians (or even the Catholic Church !) have an established opinion about it.

Comment: I guess the thing I was getting at is that I can't see a strong argument between the original quote and your proposed alternative because love, will and good are connected and desire and good are connect (As stated above). I do recall someone saying to me that Beauty is a later concept of a transcendental; whereas Truth, Goodness and Being are more classical/medieval.

Comment: @eques Yes, Wikipedia says that much about Beauty was added later.  At any rate, my later edit to the Q shows that I'm not so much want to "correct" the author of the article, but really seeking a connection between our soul's faculties and the 3 transcendentals as Catholic philosophers & the Church understand them today.  After all CCC *does* mention the 3 as truth, goodness, and beauty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141161/discussion-between-eques-and-gratefuldisciple).

Comment: There's a kind of parallel to Cranmer's view of sinful humanity: ["what the heart loves, the will chooses, and the mind justifies."](https://mbird.com/theology/ashley-null-via-thomas-cranmer-on/)